# flutter auth exception handling

Tags: flutter, authentication

i have following code for creating user and returning a translated error message

I know its an old question, but I'm still struggling with it. I followed the approach with the most upvotes of Corentin Houdayer, but its not working for me. My Try Catch is not catching the errors but rather go into Platformexception.

```
onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _email, password: _password);
                    } catch (error) {
                      _error = true;
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case ("email-already-in-use"):
                          _emessage =
                              "Du hast bereits einen Account mit der angegebenen Email-Adresse.";
                          break;
                        case ("invalid-email"):
                          _emessage = "Ungültige Email-Adresse.";
                          break;
                        case ("operation-not-allowed"):
                          _emessage =
                              "Ein unerwarteter Fehler ist aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt nocheinmal.";
                          break;
                        case ("weak-password"):
                          _emessage = "Passwort zu kurz";
                          break;
                        default:
                          _emessage =
                              "Ein unerwarteter Fehler ist aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt nocheinmal.";
                      }
                    }
```

The problem I'm facing is, my try catch is actually not catching the error, but going into Platformexception. My catch block is not even executed. What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `} catch (error) {` try using:

```
          } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            print("FirebaseAuthException code: ${e.code}");
          } on PlatformException catch (e) {
            print("PlatformException code: ${e.code}");
          }
```

to see if they catch anything. Also check if the catch is actually waiting for the .create... call to finish (can't see why it wouldn't be though).

If still no joy, try replacing the try catch code with a `.catchError()` statement after `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)`

Answer (score 1):

By seeing the code I guess you are using firebase for this operation. As per my knowledge firebase, itself will return an error if there is an error occurred. Also, instead of using such a block of code, you can declare a function and can make the signing in. May be this will be helpful cause I didn't get any error while using code like this:

```
Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password)
async {
  try{
AuthResult result= await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
FirebaseUser user = result.user;
}catch(e){
print(e.toString());
return null;
}
}
```

I suggest you refer The Net Ninja youtube channel especially the playlist of the firebase app build tutorial. You can get the link [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC). I am suggesting this cause I learned from the same playlist. Hope this helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help. I just found this:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3475

Seems to be a VSCode Issue. If I press continue on Vscode debugger, the exceptions are handled as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I raised that issue. It is not actually a VSCode issue...VSCode is just being very particular when the Uncaught Exceptions box is ticked in the debugger. It is an issue with FlutterFire library in the way they are throwing errors. Hopefully they will fix at some point.  You should have been a bit more specific on what you meant by 'Platform exception', I assumed it was an error shown in your app not VSCode